# Migrating from jboss 4.2.3 to jboss 5.1.0 getting spring related errors

Tags: spring-security, jboss

Getting below error while migrating through jboss 4.2.3 to jboss 5.1.0. Jboss 5.1.0 is not able to load spring configuration files. Additionally I have removed below errors by creating object explicitly using new keyword in the java class instead of using Spring dependency injection for “ViewCHActionHelper'”.

And I am able to resolve all the errors I was getting at the time of server startup. I am able to see my login page but when I click on login button it calls an action i.e. `Loginaction` in which I am creating an object of service class through setter getter dependency injection in this case it is throwing `Nullpointerexception`.

I believe there is some problem in loading spring configurations.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/buildClient' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper' to required type 'com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper' for property 'viewActionhelper'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] to required type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] for property 'viewActionhelper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:356)
 at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:297)
 at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:227)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
 at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
 at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
 at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
 at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
 at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
 at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
 at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
 at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
 at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
 at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
 at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
 at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
 at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper' to required type 'com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper' for property 'viewActionhelper'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] to required type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] for property 'viewActionhelper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:462)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:499)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:493)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1363)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] to required type [com.northstar.wms.cpm.ui.client.ViewCHActionHelper] for property 'viewActionhelper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
 at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
 ... 92 more
```